# UIScrollView as subview of UIView does not work with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview, masonry

I created a customView (UIView) which contains a UIScrollView as its subview, and 
objects I put on the scrollView did not show. To test it, I added a UIView to the scrollView and it didn't show neither(see code example below). Since the content I want to put on the scrollView is dynamic, I want to approach the problem by just using AutoLayout. I tried different ways and followed instructions online, none of it worked, all the similar questions were UIScrollView created inside of a UIViewController.

Here is my code, I'm using Masonry:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

@end

@implementation CustomView

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self addSubview:self.scrollView];
        [self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self);
        }];

    //Here I add someView to the scrollView, and when I create an instance of the scrollView, the someView does not show.

    self.someView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    self.someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.someView];        
    [self.someView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView);
        make.size.equalTo(CGSizeMake(40, 40));
    }];
}
return self;
}
```

Here is how I create an instance of the CustomView

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview: customView];
[customView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(64.0);
    make.height.equalTo(40.0);
    make.leading.trailing.equalTo(0);
}];
```

Is there anything I missed or did wrong that caused someView to not show?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: Does your scrollview is shown as expected? else please check if you get proper frame when you set constraint for scrollview and someview, also is there any autolayout error shown in console ?

Comment: Thank you @pyro for reminding me to put a breakpoint and check my scroll view, I tired and the view was created properly. A co-worker helped me to solve this bug by remove the redundant layer of UIView and use AutoLayout properly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by: 1).Using scrollView directly instead of as a subView in a UIView (my customView). 2) make sure to add the right and bottom constraints of the scrollView.